# MySQL LEFT JOIN syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, syntax, left-join

Quick question, just wondering if anyone can see where the syntax error is in this `LEFT JOIN`?

```
SELECT
...
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, table3 AS s3
table4 AS t4, table5 AS t5 LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6 ON t5.id = t6.t5_id
AND t6.etc
ORDER BY ...
```

I can only presume it doesn't like the `t1,t2,t3,t4` preceeding the `LEFT JOIN` on`t5 & t6`

Error description

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your 
MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'table4 AS t4, table5 AS t5  LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6 ON ON t5.id = t6' at line 26*
```

Comment: Do ***not*** mix implicit joins in the WHERE clause and explicit joins using the `JOIN` keyword. Decide upon one of them (preferrably using `JOIN`s)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have a comma "," behind `table3 as s3`

```
table3 as s3,
```

Comment: Cheers, cheers, cheers guys. Woods for trees and all that.  For what it's worth the actual SQL is about 50 lines long and was inheritted from someone who has left the company. This is a 'exampled' version of it. (Probably should have taken a minute to look at the exmapled version and would have seen that myself. That's my story and I'm sticking to it! :-)  )

Answer (score 3):

Put a comma after table3 AS s3

```
table3 AS s3,
```

Comment: For what it's worth the actual SQL is about 50 lines long and was inheritted from someone who has left the company. This is a 'exampled' version of it. (Probably should have taken a minute to look at the exmapled version and would have seen that myself. That's my story and I'm sticking to it! :-) )

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM t1 LEFT JOIN (t2, t3, t4)
                 ON (t2.a=t1.a AND t3.b=t1.b AND t4.c=t1.c)
```

Answer (score 0):

Query should be as such ,you have missed comma near to `table3 AS s3,`

```
SELECT
...
FROM table1 AS t1, table2 AS t2, table3 AS s3,
table4 AS t4, table5 AS t5 LEFT JOIN table6 AS t6 ON t5.id = t6.t5_id
AND t6.etc
ORDER BY ...
```

Correct me if 'm wrong

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned, put a comma after "table3 AS s3":

```
table3 AS s3,
```

as well as complete the expression "AND t6.etc", e.g.:

```
AND t6.etc = 1
```

or use a WHERE clause, e.g.:

```
WHERE t6.etc = 1
```

HTH (Y)

Answer (score 0):

Please refer following blog with your question answer and syntax with example: 
[Here](http://mssql-mysql.blogspot.in)